# Bad Request on PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

I am having issues with PHP curl commands using custom headers.  Can anyone see what is happening here?

```
  $url = "https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token";
  $ch = curl_init();

  $headers  = array(
    "POST https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: api.sitescout.com",
    "Authorization: Basic bGFtcGhvdXNlLWFwaTp2RmhsSmlJMm5BT****",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Length: 41"
  );

  $post_fields = array(
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
  );

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

print_r($output);

  curl_close($ch);

  //var_dump($output);
```

Here is the server response.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 05:13:09 GMT
Connection: close

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: did you solved this, i am getting same probelm, let me know if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the USERAGENT parameter also:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
```

This would mean that  what type of agent is requesting the content.

Comment: Thanks, but I could not get this to help.   I still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
$url = "https://api.sitescout.com/oauth/token";
$requestType ='POST';
$accessToken = 'Insert Your accessToken';

/* data you want to post */
$data = array(
          'subject'=>$subject,
          'starttime'=>$start,
          'endtime'=>$end, 
          'passwordrequired'=>'false'
        );

$postData = json_encode ($data);
$headers = getJsonHeaders($accessToken);

makeApiRequest($url, $requestType, $postData, $headers);

public function makeApiRequest ($url = null, $requestType = 'GET', $postData = array(),$headers = array()) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if ($requestType == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    }else if($requestType == 'PUT'){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $validResponseCodes = array(200, 201);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 

    if($requestType == 'PUT'){
        return $responseCode;
    }

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    elseif (!in_array($responseCode, $validResponseCodes)) {
        if (isJson($data)) {
            $data = json_decode($data);
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

public function getJsonHeaders ($accessToken) 
{
    return array(
        "HTTP/1.1",
        "Content-type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token=". $accessToken
    );
}

public function isJson ($string) 
{
    $isJson = 0;
    $decodedString = json_decode($string);

    if (is_array($decodedString) || is_object($decodedString)) {
        $isJson = 1;
    }

    return $isJson;
}
```

Comment: Odd, I tried this and got this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /homepages/33/d451511314/htdocs/bemixt/sitescout.php on line 88

Comment: Updated, make sure you pass data array and accesstoken according to your provided.

Comment: I actually hard coded the token straight into the function.  I still had the same stdclass error.

Comment: I have changed $this->isJson($data) into isJson($data) are sure you are using new edited code, If not then just change $this->isJson($data) into isJson($data)